# How do I setup a default shell for tmux when using nix-shell?

Tags: nix

I would like to load up `nix-shell` with `tmux` using the `fish` shell. I've accomplished this by adding to my `.nix` file:

```
shellHook = ''
  tmux -f .tmux.conf
'';
```

Then having a `.tmux.conf` that is just

```
set-option -g default-shell /nix/store/lpmzq9qf0dgn357l20y5868wayjr79yi-fish-3.3.1/bin/fish
```

I would love to get the hash out of the config file so that `tmux` will just always use the version of `fish` that `nix-shell` is currently using. Is this possible?

Comment: Relevant thread from the NixOS discourse: [Is it possible to change the default git user config for a `devShell`?](https://discourse.nixos.org/t/is-it-possible-to-change-the-default-git-user-config-for-a-devshell/17612)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have many options but I'd say the simplest solution is to use

```
shellHook =
  let tmuxConf = pkgs.writeText "tmux.conf" "set-option -g default-shell ${pkgs.fish}/bin/fish";
  in ''
    tmux -f ${tmuxConf}
  '';
```

(not tested I am on my phone, you may need to adapt the `pkgs.fish` depending on the way you load packages)